# Does not equal performing opposite in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array that looks something like

```
array (size=7)
  'car_make' => string 'BMW' (length=3)
  'car_model' => string 'M3' (length=2)
  'car_year' => string '2001' (length=4)
  'car_price' => string '10000' (length=5)
  'car_kilometers' => string '100000' (length=6)
  'paint' => string 'black' (length=5)
  'tires' => string 'pirelli' (length=7)
```

So basically there are a few base items in it that start with car_ and then a few extras.

I'm trying to search for each key that isn't car_* so paint and tires in this case. So I'm doing something like

```
foreach($_SESSION['car'][0] as $key=>$value)
{
    if($key != preg_match('/car_.*/', $key))
    {
        echo 'Match';
    }
}
```

Which I expected to echo out 2 Matches because of the 2 non car_ keys. Instead, this echos out 5 for the car_ keys.

But when I do

> if($key == preg_match('/car_.*/', $key))

It echoes out 2 Matches for the 2 non car_ keys.

Where am I messing up or misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the documentation [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) returns `true` when matching and `false` when not.  So it appears that you are having some fun with PHP's type casting.

So rather than comparing the value you should check

```
if(true === preg_match('/car_.*/', $key))
```

This should take care of it.

Also, per the documentation:

> Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is
>   contained in another string. Use [strpos()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) or [strstr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) instead as they
>   will be faster.

Which would be:

```
if(false === str_pos('car_', $key))
```

Answer (score 1):

preg_match docs say about its return values:

> preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.

So this wouldn't have worked in the first place.

I would use:

```
if ( substr($key, 0, 4) === "car_" )
```

...which is much less expensive as an operation than preg_match anyway.

Answer (score 0):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

> Return Values
>
> preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it
>   does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.

So you should compare it to 1 or to 0, not to a string.

The reason why your code was working but backwards is because comparing a number to a string produces interesting results:

From http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

1 == "" is FALSE

0 == "" is TRUE

Comment: Why does this work then? (Just not quite as intended) It returns the proper amount of 'Matches' according to the number of entries in the array, just not the right way around with != or ==.

Comment: Ahhh, funky! Thanks for that link.